# Edge animate play and stop at label

Tags: adobe-edge

What would the codes look like that would first play and stop the timeline at the label the button correspond to, I think it would look something like this:

`sym.play();`????<--codes to tell it wear to stop

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Welcome. You will get a better response if you show others what you have already tried, and any error messages. For tips on asking a good question, see [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

Go to "stop1" label and then play:

```
sym.play("stop1");
```

Go to "stop1" label and then stop:

```
sym.stop("stop1");
```

This will work only if the variable sym has the labels "stop1" and "stop2" in its timeline.
(For example if sym is the Stage and "stop1" is a label on the Stage's main timeline).